# Flaw in proof involving binomial theorem

Tags: proof-verification, binomial-coefficients, fake-proofs

Suppose we have
 $-1 < x < 0$, also an irrational $r$. We have three claims:

1. $x^r$ is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$(pretty obvious right)
2. $(1+x)^r$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$(once again, pretty obvious)
3. by binomial theorem

$$(x+1)^r = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{r \choose k}x^{r-k} $$
since $k$ is an integer, we have $r-k$ still being irrational, thus claim 1 implies that $x^{r-k}$ is undefined on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $k$, implying that every term in the summation will be undefined on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus the summation itself is undefined on $\mathbb{R}$. Then we have $(1+x)^r$ undefined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Clearly 3 contradicts 2 and 3 is wrong, but what's the flaw in my argument?

Comment: As stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), it is $x^{k}$

Comment: Take $i, -i \notin \mathbb{R}$ yet  $i -i  = 0\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

3. is wrong. The correct binomial expansion is
   $$
   (1+x)^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{r}{k}x^k,\quad |x|<1.
   $$

Comment: Yes, but this isn't the reason. The reason is Weaam's one: that complex numbers may add up to a purely real number.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get how 1 and 2 are incorrect.
I think I see why 3 is wrong now.
By your reasoning, 
1. since $x < 0$ is defined as a complex number, then $x^r$ is not defined on the reals, so my statement 1 is correct?
2. I have defined $-1 <x <0$.

Comment: 3. is incorrect because the left hand side is not equal to the right hand side.

Comment: If $x>0$ then $x^r=e^{(\log r)x}$.

Comment: you mean $x^r = e^{(log x) r}$? And also I think my claim 1 and 2 are correct

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by "not defined in $\mathbb{R}$".  I will edit my answer accordingly. And yes, I meant $x^r=e^{r\log x}$.